# How to download a file (iOS/Cocoa SDK) from URL where file name is not the part of URL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios, macos, iphone

I was wondering on how to download a file using NSUrl where the filename is not available or is not part of the request URL. I have been looking at ASIHTTPRequest (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library. It has

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/my_file.txt"];
```

But the point is you need to know the file name here. For example if you put the URL (not real URL) `http://some-website/foo.pdf`

It downloads a file foo.pdf and I want to save it like that. Any ideas thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the NSURLConnection delegate callback `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` you can retrieve the `suggestedFileName` from the [`NSURLResponse`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLResponse). If you get unknown for a name then you need to come up with another name for your file. At this point you can specify your download path before you start saving data.

> suggestedFilename
>
> Returns a suggested
>   filename for the response data.
>
> - (NSString *)suggestedFilename
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A suggested filename for the
>   response data.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The method tries to create
>   a filename using the following, in
>   order:
>
> 1. A filename specified using the content
>      disposition header.
> 2. The last path
>      component of the URL.
> 3. The host of the
>      URL.
>
> If the host of URL can't be
>   converted to a valid filename, the
>   filename “unknown” is used.
>
> In most cases, this method appends the
>   proper file extension based on the
>   MIME type. This method will always
>   return a valid filename regardless of
>   whether or not the resource is saved
>   to disk.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later. Declared In NSURLResponse.h