# How to track user downloads with cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-elcapitan

Getting to brass tacks, I need to track when the user downloads a file from the internet. *(For example, say a user is in Safari and clicks "Download Now" on an sdk from developer.apple.com and starts a download)*

**1)** How can I see that event?

**2)** How can I see what is downloaded?

**3)** Can you please give api's and/or documentation links too!!

**Note:** This should be OS X 10.11 capable code at minimum. I'm less worried about backtracking then being ahead of the game as this app is not planned for release for another year.

Also, should this be more of an idea slated for a Safari Extension, please give ideas/documentation/code for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad a question. There are plenty of examples online for managing starting asynchronous downloads. What you're asking for, really, is how to download a file and how to build a user interface around it.

For the first part, try searching for "how to download a file" or something similar. You'll find plenty of results [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436599/how-to-download-a-file-ios-cocoa-sdk-from-url-where-file-name-is-not-the-part). There are even third-party frameworks to make this much easier.

For the second, there are many ways and you're going to have to decide on a direction, try it, and post specific questions for specific problems you encounter.

Comment: I don't need to download a file. Just see when a user started to in anoth application (such as Safari, Chrome, or Firefox). Downloading a file would do me no good.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to specify this. If you want to do something more like Little Snitch (outbound network connection monitor / firewall), you'll need to write a kernel extension and install it on the user's computer with administrator permissions, since no user-space app can or should be able to monitor other processes for what should be obvious security reasons. There is no API, as you asked, to do such a thing for the same reasons. You also won't be able to distribute it through the App Store, since Apple doesn't allow such behavior.

Comment: This is a security program being designed, and not expected to go on the app store. But thanks for you help anyways.